# Struts2 s:set tag doesn't work for some variable names

Tags: java, struts2

Consider the following snippet on my jspPage:

```
<s:set var="selectedAccount" value="userSelectedAccount"/>
<s:set var="rootAccount" value="userRootAccount"/>

<p>name:<s:property value="%{#rootAccount.getName()}"/></p>
<p>equals: <s:if test='%{#selectedAccount.equals(#rootAccount)}'>true</s:if></p>
```

I expected to the see the following output in my browser:

```
name: account5
equals: true
```

For some reason it doesn't seem to work and I see only the hardcoded text:

```
name:
equals:
```

Inside my IDE (Eclipse) I see that the equals method is actually being executed and it returns true! What sorcery is this? So I got desperate and tried fiddling with everything. In the end I found it works if I change the var="..." to something else:

```
<s:set var="randomstring" value="userRootAccount"/>
<s:set var="notroottest" value="userRootAccount"/>
```

However it doesn't work with the following names:

```
<s:set var="root" value="userRootAccount"/>
<s:set var="roottest" value="userRootAccount"/>
<s:set var="rootAccount" value="userRootAccount"/>
```

This randomness makes no sense. I have no other variables or properties called "root" or "roottest" or rootAccount" anywhere, and also no getRoot() or getRootAccount() methods. The only thing I do have is a method getUserRootAccount() which returns an account object. What mistake did I make?

Comment: So far it doesn't look particularly random, at least all the var names that start with `root`. This doesn't explain `selectedAccount`, though. There *is* a root variable called, unsurprisingly, `root`; perhaps OGNL does a `startsWith`. This still does not explain `selectedAccount`, though, which I find surprising. Please update the question with the specific version of S2 and any deviations from the default dependencies, like if you changed the OGNL version.

Comment: Normal struts2.3.16 and no changes to OGNL. I think your assumption is right: everything that STARTS with root doesn't work. but vars like "aroot" or "_root" do work!

Comment: Still doesn't explain `selectedAccount`, though.

Comment: It is OGNL thing. And your `if` isn't working because you are trying to pass `#rootAccount` inside it.

Comment: @AleksandrM: my if IS working if I don't use a var name that starts with root.

Comment: @Dave Newton: what's wrong with selectedAccount? It has always worked fine (which is what I expected). Perhaps the reason the equals test returns true in java but the "true" doesn't get through to the jsp page is because it the first thing is evaluated in some sort of "jsp context" and the other in "a java context"?

Comment: @user1884155: Of course it is. So just don't use var name that starts with root. The `selectedAccount` is working just fine, but you are passing `#rootAccount` inside equals which isn't working.

Comment: @user1884155 Nothing, that's why I think it's weird that you said it wasn't working, but re-reading it's the `root` part that's throwing it off-my bad.